# Maven - how to replace a custom token in a file with a dynamic value from a Java class method or static property?

Tags: java, maven

I'm seeking a way to add to replace a custom token in a file, such as "[!![ TOKEN ]!!]", with a value from a Java class method or property.

I'm new to Java in general so my knowledge of Maven is low, as such I haven't had much success searching for what's I'm looking for. Plenty of ways to replace tokens with static values but not looked up or generated values from external code.

Also to clarify I don't want to modify the source file only the compiled output. The source should remain unchanged to avoid needing to check-in a new version.

**Example:**

*File to parse (splash.html)*:

```html
<div>Version: [!![ CURRENT_VERSION_EXTERNAL_NAME ]!!]</div>
```

Our codebase already has a Java class `AppVersion.class` so I'm hoping to replace the token with  the value of something like `foo.AppVersion.getExternalVersion()`.

Thanks ahead of time for any and all help.

Comment: From the description, it's hard to guess what your are looking for, but maybe https://freemarker.apache.org will help you. Here you have a sample: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jpp

Answer (score 0):

```
String document = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(file.getAbsolutePath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
document = document.replace("[!![ CURRENT_VERSION_EXTERNAL_NAME ]!!]", AppVersion.getExternalVersion());
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, document, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Does this fulfill you demands?

Comment: Thanks for the response however I'm seeking more of a how-to for accomplishing the find action in the Maven workflow context, then replacing the found token with the result of a function.

Hope that helps clarify things.